# Segment formed by a point inside a circle and a point outside intersects the circle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

O is the center of the circle of radius r. We have two points A and B | OA < r and OB > r. I have to prove that AB intercepts the circle.
I tried to use the line segment that contains AB to build a perpendicular line that intercepts O, the point of intersection of these two lines I called C. So I formed 2 right triangles, OCA and OCB. I tried to use the Pythagorean theorem, but I cannot relate these triangles to find the point of intersection of the line segment that contais AB with the circle.

Can someone help me?
Sorry for my bad English, I don't know much of that language

Comment: What is the meaning of "| OA r." in the first line ?

Comment: You have to prove it by pure geometry or analytical (coordinates) geometry ?

Comment: The proof depends strongly on the axiomatic system that describes the geometry. Please specify a bit about it.

Comment: Such that the OA line segment is smaller than the radius of the circle. Pure geometry, using the axioms of Euclidean geometry